# Unable to install agda via homebrew in mac os x M1 chip

Tags: agda, agda-mode

I was following the instruction [here](https://agda.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting-started/installation.html#os-x) and it said to do:

```
brew install agda
agda-mode setup
```

I believe it should be working since I was able to compile the `hello-world.agda` and run the binary executable with `./hello-world`.
But the output says there are error:

```
(meta_learning) brandomiranda~ ❯ brew install agda
Warning: No available formula with the name "agda".
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
Error: No formulae found in taps.
```

In fact, I don't know what changed since my last compilation of hello world but indeed I cannot compile it (and thus run it) anymore:

```
(meta_learning) brandomiranda~/coq4brando/cs598 ❯ agda --compile hello-world.agda
/Users/brandomiranda/.agda/libraries:1:  Failed to read library file /usr/local/lib/agda/standard-library.agda-lib.
Reason: /usr/local/lib/agda/standard-library.agda-lib: openFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)
```

Why? Does someone know how to fix this?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't have a legacy install of Agda? If homebrew says there is no formula then it won't even try to install it as it does not know how...